# How do you calculate the number of elements conjugate to a particular permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Working in $S_n$, and given a particular permutation, how would you go about calculating the number of conjugate elements to the permutation?

I guess since two elements are conjugate iff they have the same cycle type this gives some restriction on the conjugate elements. I know two elements, say $x$ and $y$, are conjugate if $g^{-1}\cdot x\cdot g=y$ for some $g$ in the group but I'm not sure how to work out the number of conjugate elements.

As an example, the permutation is $x = (12)(34)(56789)$, working in $S_{12}$. So $x$ has cycle type $[2,2,5,1,1,1]$ so clearly any conjugate elements must have cycle type $[2,2,5,1,1,1]$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You already know the key for solving the problem. The rest is simple *combinatorics*: how many ways can you choose $2+2+5$ elements out of $n$?

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: If the permutation in $S_n$ has cycle type $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_k)$, start by figuring out how many ways there are to distribute $n$ numbers into boxes of size $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_k$.  Then, once you have a box with $\mu_i$ numbers in it, how many distinct cycles can you produce?  Finally, you have to account for the fact that some of the $\mu_i$'s might be equal, and you get the same permutation if you reorder the disjoint cycles.

This is worked out carefully in volume 1 of Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics*, as well as other combinatorics texts.

Comment: Chapter 1, prop. 1.3.2, page 18 (Ed. of 1997)

Answer (score 5):

For the given example, you just have to count the possible $[2,2,5]$ groupings of $12$ elements. Note that if we exchange the two $2$-cycles, we get the same permutation.

Now it can go like: first choose $2$ elements out of $12$, then $10$ elements are left, choose $2$ again, and then choose $5$ elements out of the rest ($8$), finally divide it by $2!$ because the order of the first two chosen group doesn't matter, that is:
$$\frac1{2!}\cdot\binom{12}2\cdot \binom{10}2\cdot\binom85$$

Comment: +1 I am thinking of doing the problem using GAP for example for $S_3$

Comment: @Berci: Your number does not match with the answer. A factor $4!$ is missing. Can you please modify your arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation in $S_n$ consisting of $a_1$ fixed points, $a_2$ (disjoint) transpositions, $a_3$ three-cycles, ..., $a_n$ number of $n$-cycles.

Of course, if there's no cycle of  length $i$, we set $a_i=0$. As you would expect, $\sum i\cdot a_i=n$ where $1\leq i\leq n$.

The number of conjugates of $\sigma$ is given by $$|\mathrm c_{S_n}(\sigma)|=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^n (i)^{a_i}\cdot(a_i !)}$$

In particular, for $(12)(34)(56789)\in S_{12}$, we have $a_1=3$, $a_2=2$, $a_5=1$ and size of the conjugacy class is $\frac{12!}{1^3\cdot 3!\cdot2^2\cdot 2!\cdot 5^1\cdot 1!}=1,995,840$.

**Intuition behind the formula**:

Disjoint cycles commute and there $a_i$ number of $i$-cycles. This is why we divide by $(a_i)!$.

Every $i$-cycle, say, $(12\ldots i)$ is unique upto cyclic rotation i.e., $(12\ldots i)=(2\ldots i1)=\cdots =(i\ldots21)\tag*{}$
So each $i$-cycle is accompanied with a division by $i$... Hence, net division by $(i)^{a_i}$ because, recall that, there are $a_i$ number of $i$-cycles.