# Number of elements in $S_6$ conjugate to $(123)(456)$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Find the number of elements in $S_6$ conjugate to $(123)(456)$

I know we're only looking at elements in $S_6$ with the same cycle type as $(123)(456)$ (two 3-cycles).

So we have the following:

$$\frac{6\cdot 5 \cdot 4}{3}\cdot \frac{3\cdot 2 \cdot 1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=40$$

But this question has been asked before and there was a different answer:
[How do you calculate the number of elements conjugate to a particular permutation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311163/how-do-you-calculate-the-number-of-elements-conjugate-to-a-particular-permutatio?rq=1)

I know mine is right but why is the other wrong? Is it because we are totally disregarding order, i.e. we're acting as if $(123)=(213)$?

Comment: Where do you see a wrong answer on the linked page?

Comment: Well, if we follow the first answer of the linked page we get $\frac1{2!}\cdot\binom{6}3\cdot \binom{3}3=10$

Comment: Right, [Berci's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/311175/206402) doesn't distinguish between the different 5-cycles that permute the same elements, which does look wrong.

Comment: Your answer of 40 is correct. Here is a detailed structure of $S_6$ to further convince you http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S6